# How to configure kubelet systemd-managed service to specific node

Tags: kubernetes, systemd, kubelet

I thinking about how configure kubelet systemd-managed service to specific node. I tried to find any hint in **/etc/kubernetes/manifests** folder but i cannot find any variable where i can define value of the node. Any advice ?

Answer (score 3):

If you run

```
$ systemctl status kubelet
kubelet.service - kubelet: The Kubernetes Node Agent
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/kubelet.service; disabled; vendor preset: enabled)
  Drop-In: /etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d
           └─10-kubeadm.conf
   Active: active (running) since Thu 2020-05-21 19:47:01 UTC; 1 day 20h ago
     Docs: http://kubernetes.io/docs/
 Main PID: 3104 (kubelet)
    Tasks: 18 (limit: 2161)
   Memory: 46.1M
   CGroup: /system.slice/kubelet.service
           └─3104 /var/lib/minikube/binaries/v1.15.7/kubelet --authorization-mode=Webhook --bootstrap-kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/bootstrap-kubelet.conf --cgroup-driver=cgroupfs --client-ca-file=/var/lib/minikube/certs/ca.crt --cluster-dns=10.96.0.10 --cluster-domain=cluster.local --config=/var/lib/kubelet/config.yaml --container-runtime=docker --fail-swap-on=false --hostname-override=minikube --kubeconfig=/etc/kubernetes/kubelet.conf --node-ip=192.168.99.100 --pod-manifest-path=/etc/kubernetes/manifests
```

You can get all the information here.

`10-kubeadm.conf` located in following directory.

```
/etc/systemd/system/kubelet.service.d/
```

Comment: I updated answer. Do you need any other specific information?

Comment: That is what i was looking for. Thanks

Comment: would you mind accepting the answer if it satisfy  your question @O.Man